# Can't see what was been checked

Tags: php, css, symfony

Creating a checkbox -

```
->add('price_type', 'checkbox', array(
                                    'value' => 'minimal',
                                    'empty_data' => 'fixed',
                                    'label' => 'Not fixed',
                                    'required' => false))
```

on page itself it's fine, but no changing if I click on it. Also - when form submitted - this field has 'checked' value.

Comment: Post here your code where you process your form and where problem occurs

Comment: This seems like an odd JS problem. Do you use some checkbox widget?

Comment: @JovanPerovic Yes, you are right, it was an evil js script. =)